# getting inside column data change data frame to panda

Tags: python, pyspark

i am using Databricks with pyspark
and i have data in data frame which i am converting in Panda, which change data sequence of array type inside of my column.
same issue if i do `dataframe.collect()`.

code snipped

```
    result_df = prule_val.groupBy("CUSTOMER_CODE").agg(
        collect_list("PRULE_CODE_PARSED").alias("prule_codes_list"),
        collect_list("TOTAL_SALES").alias("A")
    )

pandasDF = result_df.toPandas()
    filtered_df = pandasDF[pandasDF['CUSTOMER_CODE'] == '0070331037']
```

screen shot of result before and after convert.

[image]

what are we doing wrong or possible reason of that?

Comment: Are you using AWS or Azure databricks??

Comment: @DileeprajnarayanThumula AWS

Comment: spark is lazy. so, it will rerun all steps every time you execute an action (`.show()`, `.toPandas()`, etc.). couple that with collect_list's behavior of not retaining the dataframe's order because of the distributed nature of spark.